# please tell me how DNS works in linux with commands and debugging aswell

Tags: linux, dns

i want to understand the flow happens when we type some URL into the browser and how to debug if something nowt working using linux commands

Answer (score 2):

The Linux system ships with a number of system libraries, including an implementation of `sys/sockets.h` for C programs which implements the [Berkeley Sockets API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standards. The POSIX spec includes the definition of a [method](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) called `getaddrinfo()` which returns the IP address of the host to a program that needs it. Each programming runtime (eg [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html#getaddrinfo()-%2f-getnameinfo()-ERROR-CONSTANTS), [php](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php), etc) implements its own interfaces by which they call [getaddrinfo()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo) but most of them actually use the kernel's method to actually process a DNS request.

A sockets connection involves a number of method calls, including socket(), bind(), connect(), etc. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/984182/what-are-the-detailed-osi-model-steps-involved-in-connecting-to-a-website/984253#984253) on how those calls are coordinated to created a network connection.

Troubleshooting DNS resolution on the client end just comes down to Server and Cache. The server will respond with the address it knows for the destination, but if its not the address you want for whatever reason (geolocation, blacklisting, etc), you can change servers to one that has the address you want. If you are connecting to a server with the address you want, but are still getting a bad result, it may be caused by a cached response on your host or upstream at a router or caching proxy.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you linked to also mentions that gethostname is now considered a legacy interface, and that geraddrinfo should be used instead.

Comment: Updated per your assertion. Several of the languages I linked haven't implemented a new method name for their internal function (likely for legacy compatibility) but I've updated links for those that have.

Answer (score 2):

> **[I] want to understand the flow happens when we type some URL into the browser**

See for example

- My [Journey of a Web Request](https://superuser.com/a/528010/52492)
- Frank's [What are the detailed OSI model steps involved in connecting to a website?](https://superuser.com/a/984205/52492)

> **and how to debug**

The most useful tools are probably

- `tcpdump`.
- `nslookup` or its more modern equivalents `host` and `dig`.
- `wget` or `curl`.
  Read their manpages to find out useful options like

  - `--server-response`,
  - `--debug`,
  - `--verbose`,
  - `--no-dns-cache`

You need to understand local name resolution first though because there are name services that may be used before DNS (e.g. local hosts files and also in some rare setups, other network services such as NBNS, YP, etc). I'd start by reading `man resolv.conf`