# Local Network Subdomain Access

Tags: networking, dns, hosts, hostname

Im trying to set up a local network subdomain that is accessible to the entire local network.  This is Ubuntu Server 20.04.  I've modified `/etc/hosts` as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 nas.local
...
127.0.1.1 subdomain.nas.local
...
```

I can ping the domain `subdomain.nas.local` locally, but I cannot ping it from within the network.  I am sure I am misunderstanding how this works.  How can I set this up to resolve correctly?

Comment: Are you expecting it to resolve through mDNS (avahi-daemon) or through regular DNS (home router)?

Comment: @user1686 Im not sure what you mean.  Ive set the router up so that the IP is static, and set up `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` on the server.  I havent had to do more than that just for the basic `nas.local` domain.  Now that I would like to add a subdomain though, it's not as straightforward.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is shorthand for "me". You're telling everything that when it sees the URL 'nas.local' it shouldn't look outside itself for it.

Comment: What you are attempting to do with `127.0.0.1` is impossible.  `127.0.0.1` is universally assumed to be the current machine.  You will want to set `subdomain.nas.local` to whatever the local intranet address of your NAS actually is.

Comment: @Ramhound I dont understand.  How does http://nas.local work on any machine on the network then?

Comment: @addohm: Certainly not by being in your /etc/hosts. There are at least two (or more) commonly used ways to make .local names work on the LAN, but the important point is that none of them "announce" /etc/hosts entries. Even if it _looks_ related, it's still only for the machine itself.

Comment: @addohm - It won’t as you have currently defined it.

Comment: ok so the problem here is you are trying to use zero-conf networking, but want to configure it, which is ... well contradictory.  .local is generally associated with Zero-conf/AVAHI networks, where the hosts all use multicast DNS, and respond to requests for names themselves (as hostname.local), instead of using a central DNS server.  The issue here is that a system doesn't usually have two hostnames (while having multiple DNS names is common). your hostfile hack isn't going to do much to help.  So that's why hostname and hostname.local works, but any other expression doesn't.

Comment: @FrankThomas do you have a proposed solution?  I am quite flexible as I am just in the beginnings of this server setup...relatively.

Comment: My recommendation is implement a dns server, and stop using `.local`. Just pick your own domain name for internal purposes (you don't need to register it or anything), configure a zone for it on your DNS, and configure forwarding so that queries your DNS server can't resolve locally are forwarded on to public servers of your choice. then configure DHCP to give clients your DNS server address instead of one upstream.

Answer (score 0):

If the default gateway is a local router that provides DHCP and DNS service for the "local" domain then that router recognises the local IP-address (not the 127.0.0.1 loopback address) of an ethernet interface of your Ubuntu server and provides that IP-address to other devices on your LAN that use DNS to lookup "nas.local".

You might either need to setup a separate DNS server, which might give you better control, or find out if your router's firmware provides a way to create statically administered subdomains.

Entries in `/etc/hosts` are only visible to the local machine (unless you use some ancient and obsolete tools like NIS/YP to replicate data). To work with subdomains I would certainly set up a primary and maybe a secondary DNS server but there is a fair bit to learn about DNS configuration and how to handle DHCP clients.

Comment: Sounds like I need a local DNS then.  Something like this should help?  https://blog.eldernode.com/private-dns-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/  My router's DHCP allows me to set a DNS.

Comment: Its interesting.  Im really starting to wonder how this all comes together.  When I go to http://nas I get one site, when I go to http://nas.local I get another.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/528010/52492